# Display Uploaded Image smaller in size php

Tags: image, image-size

I have a folder in which all my images will be uploaded, I want to create a div where the uploaded images are displayed in a smaller size.

I do not want to save the smaller versions of the uploaded pic, I just want to display them in a smaller size.

The uploaded files are already in 100x100 size so i don't have to bother about the proportionality

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything, Though i can guess this can be achieved by using height= and width =  in the <a img tags

Answer (score 0):

just use css to set the size you want:

```
div img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Route (inline):

```
<div class="normal image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" width="100" /></div>
<div class="smaller image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" width="75" /></div>
<div class="half image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" width="50" /></div>
<div class="tiny" image><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" width="25" /></div>
```

CSS Route:

```
<div class="normal image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" /></div>
<div class="smaller image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" /></div>
<div class="half image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" /></div>
<div class="tiny image"><img src="images/imgsrc.jpg" /></div>
<style type="text/css">
.image img{width:90px;}
.normal img{width:auto;}
.smaller img{width:75px;}
.half img{width:50px;}
.tiny img{width:25px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Will this adjust the height automatically?

Comment: The browser will scale the image's height proportionally in both cases, yes.